# In this proof, why does definition of Lebesgue outer measure imply existence of open superset that is arbitrarily larger?

Tags: measure-theory

I am currently reading *Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis* by Sheldon Axler and I am in the middle of the proof for the following lemma:

> Suppose $B ⊆ \mathbb{R}$ is a Borel set. Then for every $ε > 0$, there exists a closed set
> $F ⊆ B$ such that $|B\setminus F| < ε$.

The proof begins thus:

> Let $L$ be the set containing all $D⊆\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a closed set $F ⊆ D$ such that $|D \setminus F| < \epsilon$.
>
> The strategy of the proof is to show that L is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then because $L$ contains every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (if $D ⊆ \mathbb{R}$ is closed, take $F = D$ in the definition of $L$), by taking complements we can conclude that $L$ contains every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and thus every Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

After showing $L$ is closed under countable intersections, it proceeds to show it is closed under complementation.

> Now we want to prove that L is closed under complementation. Suppose $D ∈ L$ and $ε > 0$. We want to show that there is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}\setminus D$ whose set difference with $\mathbb{R} \setminus D$ has outer measure less than $ε$, which will allow us to conclude that $\mathbb{R} \setminus D ∈ L$.
>
> First we consider the case where $|D| < ∞$. Let $F ⊆ D$ be a closed set such that $|D \setminus F| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. The definition of outer measure implies that there exists an open set $G$ such that $D ⊆ G$ and $|G|<|D|+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

I’m having trouble with the last sentence. The book defines “outer measure” to be the infimum of sums $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{l(I_n)}$ over all possible open covers $\{I_n\}$ and where $l$ is the length of an open interval. How does this imply that an open set containing $D$ exists that is less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ bigger than $D$ in measure?

I suppose the definition implies that there exist open sets of the form $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}{I_n}$ that contain $D$, but it does not imply that for every $x \ge |D|$, there exists an open cover for which $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{l(I_n)}=x$ (as I would assume to need to be the case if we are to be able to find a $G$ that is $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ greater than $D$ in measure for any arbitrary $\epsilon >0$), does it?

Comment: Why do you need th fact that for every $x \ge |D|$, there exists an open cover for which $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{l(I_n)}=x$. You seem to have some problem with the definition of infimum.

Comment: @geetha290krm Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily chosen, to always be able to find a $G$ for any $D$ such that $|G| < |D| + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ would require there to be a $G$ for every $x\ge |D|$ such that $|G|=x$, wouldn’t it?   But I’m not sure where the existence of such $G$ comes from or what the book means when it says that the definition of outer measure implies the existence of a $G$ with $|G| -|D|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Comment: Infimum of $\{0,1\}$ is $0$. Does it mean that every number $x \ge 0$ belongs to this set?

Comment: @geetha290krm I think I understand what you mean. I’ve thought about it more and I think I’ve got it, but I have another question. Since $|D|$ is the infimum of $\sum^\infty_{n=1}{l(I_n)}$, $|D|\le\sum^\infty_{n=1}{l(J_n)}$, where $\{J_n\}$ is the “smallest” open cover containing $D$. By subadditivity, we have $|\bigcup_{n>0}J_n| \le \sum^\infty_{n=1}{l(J_n)}$, but we also have $|D| \le |\bigcup_{n>0}J_n|$ since $D \subseteq \bigcup_{n>0}J_n$. Wouldn’t this imply that $|D| = |\bigcup_{n>0}J_n|$? (I understand that the proof works just fine if this were the case, but I just wanted to confirm.)

Comment: There is no such thing as smallest open cover and you did not prove that $|D| \ge |\cup J_n|$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Very well. Take $\{I_n\}$ to be any open cover containing $D$. By subadditivity we have $|\bigcup I_n| \le \sum{l(I_n)}$, and by subset inclusion we have $|D| \le |\bigcup I_n|$. Therefore we have $|D| \le |\bigcup I_n| \le \sum{l(I_n)}$ for any $\{I_n\}$. Since $|D|$ is the infimum of such sums, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \{I_n\}$ such that $\sum{l(I_n)} \le |D| + \epsilon$, and that then means $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \{I_n\}$, such that $|\bigcup I_n| \le |D| + \epsilon$. Thus we have the $G$ in the proof. Is my interpretation correct?